# Applying for masters in a field different than what I have experience in

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, computer-science

I am sorry this is a bit long, I tried to keep it as short as possible. So please bear with me.

I am currently in the final year of my undergraduate course and am planning to apply for masters in computer graphics, and although I have a significant experience in graphics (by working on shaders and image effects for games as I am heavily interested in game development), I don't have any academic research work, or recommendations in that field and moreover none of the professors in my university are actively working in that field whom I can work with.

I do have research based work in AI and natural language processing including a research paper but only because a lot of my professors and peers were enthusiastic in the field whom I could work with and also I had somewhat interest in that field. But its not something I would want to pursue masters in.

My question is how do I make my application such that I can represent myself as a valuable and worthy candidate for a course in computer graphics even though I have little experience in it. And also will showing in my application (SOP) that I have research work in AI and not in computer graphics weaken it, as it will portray me as someone whose not focused towards this track, or for some other reason? Or would it actually be beneficial to include that?

Comment: @mhwombat: Do note that the answers to that question are, depending on the interpretation, either somewhat place-specific or PhD-specific. I feel they do not quite apply to Masters degrees in some European countries (and the country is not specified here).

Comment: The answer in that link talks about two different degrees which might be as disparate as engineering and economics . The fields that i am asking about are pretty similar to each other , so i was hoping to get a more definite answer than the one in the link. And i am planning on applying to colleges in usa onlg and i am currently from india